# Как записать изменения по шаблону в один файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Как я могу записать изменения без создания нового файла (low.txt)?

Задача: перед каждым словом ' BACKSPACE ' (читается с пробелами)  в файле необходимо убрать 1 символ. Например: файл содержит следующие данные: Hello, **user** BACKSPACE. После запуска программы должно получиться: Hello, **use** BACKSPACE

```
from pynput.keyboard import *
import re


def keyboardControl():
    keyboard = Controller()


def writeToFile(key):
    key = str(key).replace("'", '')

    if key == 'Key.backspace':
        key = ' BACKSPACE '

    with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(key)

    s = ""
    with open('log.txt') as f:
        s = f.read()
        s = re.sub(r".\sBACKSPACE", " BACKSPACE", s)
    with open('low.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(s)


with Listener(on_press=writeToFile) as l:
    l.join()
```

Comment: По Вашему описанию из `Hello, user BACKSPACE` должно получиться `Hello, userBACKSPACE`, а не `Hello, use BACKSPACE`. Сформулируйте точно, что Вам надо.

Comment: Именно это мне и нужно

Comment: Перед BACKSPACE и после стоят пробелы (в коде)